# Which folder should I use to save user's photo taken by app

Tags: ios, storage, photo

I'm developing photo app but my app has rejected twice because of iOS Data Storage Guideline.

I don't know an exact folder which saving user's contents (In this case, user's photo taken by my app).
I guess '/Documents' could be answer, but I have no confidence.

Comment: Which two locations were you using to store the images when your app got rejected?

Comment: At first, I stored web downloaded contents and user's photo in /library Folder, and rejected.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the images inside the apps document folder or can save the paths to images .

Answer (score 1):

You can create you own sub directory of document i.e Documents/Photos. You can check they are saving to the correct place by enabling iTunes to access the documents folder and checking that they are being written to the correct place.

Comment: is it ok to use Documents directiry? (not using sub directory)